# PHP - 'preg_replace regex' all images' URL

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I tried to replace all image URLs with an other image URL but I didn't success to correctly write the regex.

My images are not necessarily in an `img` tag with `src=""`.

It is mostly enclosed with `="image url"`

Content to replace for example:

```
[side_section poster="image.jpg" position="left" bgrepeat="no-repeat" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" paddingtop="70" paddingbot="70" txtcolor="" ]

$content = (string) preg_replace('/(?[!=")(http:\\/\\/.+(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp))/Ui', './images/placeholder.png', (string) $content);
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample URLs, and show us what you expect ?

Comment: I'm worried when I see `(?[!=")`. Try to use an online tool like regex101.com. I'm also a bit worried about the random type casts you make.

Comment: I know I'm really not good at that. My image will always be like that: `[... ="image.jpg"  ...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
$content = '[side_section poster="image.jpg" position="left" bgrepeat="no-repeat" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" paddingtop="70" paddingbot="70" txtcolor="" ]';
$newContent = (string) preg_replace('/="([^"]*\.(?:png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp))"/', '="./images/placeholder.png"', (string) $content);
echo $newContent;
```

The regex used is: `="([^"]*\.(?:png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp))"`

You can test the it here: **[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tM7jT6/5)**

However the string that you use to replace your image paths should look like this: `'="./images/placeholder.png"'`

As an alternative use this function:

```
function replaceImg($content, $path)
{
    return (string) preg_replace('/="([^"]*\.(?:png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp))"/', '="'.$path.'"', (string) $content);
}
```

---

**example**:

```
$content = '[side_section poster="image.jpg" position="left" bgrepeat="no-repeat" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" paddingtop="70" paddingbot="70" txtcolor="" ]';
echo replaceImg($content, './images/placeholder.png');
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[side_section poster="./images/placeholder.png" position="left" bgrepeat="no-repeat" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" paddingtop="70" paddingbot="70" txtcolor="" ]
```

---

**example 2**:

```
$content = 'position="left" poster="image.jpg"';
echo replaceImg($content, './images/placeholder.png');
```

**OUTPUT**

```
position="left" poster="./images/placeholder.png"
```

Comment: instead of using `.*` use `[^"]*` otherwise something like `position="left" poster="image.jpg"` will give you wrong results.

Comment: it don't works with attribute before: `test1="something" test2="image.jpg"`